# Cakephp 3 notBlank validation message not showing

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm facing a problem with the validation message upon the notBlank rule.
(I use notBlank as notEmpty has been deprecated).

I tried to change the default validation message with notBlank rule which is '***This field cannot be left empty***' to a custom one.

**What I did works with all the other rules (including notEmpty) but does not work for notBlank and I don't understand why....**

I tried in the both folowing ways :

```
$validator
            ->requirePresence('title', true, MSG_FORM_FIELD_REQUIRED)
            ->add("title", [
                "notBlank" => [
                    "rule" => "notBlank",
                    "message" => MSG_FORM_FIELD_REQUIRED
                ]
            ]);
```

**OR**

```
    $validator
        ->requirePresence('title', true, MSG_FORM_FIELD_REQUIRED)
        ->notBlank('title', MSG_FORM_FIELD_REQUIRED);
```

Am I missing something there ?

Comment: I made the same mistake in thinking `notEmpty` is deprecated. There used to be two `notEmpty` functions, only one is deprecated. You can still use `$validator->notEmpty(...)`. `notBlank` is for use with the `$validator->add` method, like your first example (which does look like it should work...)

Answer (score -2):

CakePHP 3+, just simply define `notBlank` and `notEmpty` together.

```
 $validator
    ->notEmpty('title', true, MSG_FORM_FIELD_REQUIRED)
    ->notBlank('title', MSG_FORM_FIELD_REQUIRED);
```

// Note: add `notEmpty` before `notBlank` method, plz refer https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/5856